# VS2008 crashes with xml when in project

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2008, crash

Having an issue with vs2008, anytime I have an xml file in a project and go to open it, devenv crashes out. Not specific xml files, but all I've tried. Have reinstalled vs2008 and run devenv /safemode. If I open the same xml file directly without a project, no problems. Any Ideas?

Unhandled exception at 0x76f76541 in devenv.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

```
Call Stack Shows:
>   ntdll.dll!76f76541()    
    [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll] 
    F981BBED.x86.dll!35672d05()     
    user32.dll!759c8d88()   
    user32.dll!759c9185()   
    mscorwks.dll!705fc370()     
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.ni.dll!673362f9()    
    System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll!67dd86a0()  
    System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll!67dd8621()  
    System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll!6830a167()  
    user32.dll!759cf8d2()   
    user32.dll!759cf794()   
    user32.dll!759cf73d()   
    user32.dll!759d0817()   
    oleaut32.dll!75a541ec()     
    user32.dll!759d0a65()   
    ntdll.dll!76f899ce()    
    user32.dll!759d02c5()   
    user32.dll!759ca104()   
    msenv.dll!61387561()    
    devenv.exe!2f1caabc()   
    devenv.exe!2f1c78f2()   
    advapi32.dll!760df2f5()     
    advapi32.dll!760df1c0()     
    advapi32.dll!760df594()     
    ntdll.dll!76f87f54()    
    advapi32.dll!760df405()     
    advapi32.dll!760df4d5()     
    advapi32.dll!760df4d5()     
    devenv.exe!2f1c1ea4()   
    kernel32.dll!758f4911()     
    ntdll.dll!76f6e4b6()    
    ntdll.dll!76f6e489()
```

Comment: Can you try the following: change the extension of your XML file to .txt and open it in VS. If it opens, than it's the rendering that kills it. Maybe you need to re-install MSXML, or your IE. If it doesn't open, you have a corrupt VS installation.

Comment: Renamed and it opened fine. Tried reinstalling msxml 6. Same issue. Did already repair the vs2008, guess I'll start the long uninstall/reinstall to see if that helps.

Comment: Full Uninstall/Reinstall... Same issue

Comment: msxml 3 and 4 repaired and uninstalled/reinstalled IE8, same issue

Comment: Sorry it didn't help. It sounds like you may have some sort of a deeper problem, if it persists across installations - something may be corrupt in your OS.
I hesitate to suggest it - and please don't act upon this advice without considering the implications - but maybe you can restore your OS to the last restore point in which you could open xml files.

Comment: Been playing around with the settings and such. Wierd thing is that I can right click and open the file with the source editor in vs2008 and it works fine. After that I can open it in the xml view and it works also. But once I close and reopen vs2008, if I try to first open with the xml editor I get the crash again.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Service pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en) for VS2008, which solves other editor-related problems (xaml editor performance for one). Maybe it helps this, too.

Comment: Installed, no luck. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

If that isn't the Express edition, why not ask in a MS forum or even open a support case? I presume the developers at MS are quite interested in a reproducible crash.

Comment: Already put it up on https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=477146 , just wanted to get some work done over the weekend. I do have a premium subscription to msdn and this is vs2008 pro.

Comment: I see. Sorry for suggesting the obvious. Good luck!